# Merging 3 lists of objects holding references to other objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists for each of the following two types (Both are a compact version of a bit more complex types):

```
class Person
{
    public Guid ID {get; set;}
    public Account PrivateAccount { get; set; }
    public Account SharedAccount { get; set; }
}

class Account
{
    public Guid AccountId {get; set;}
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

And I also created the following type:

```
class PersonWithAmounts
{
    public Guid PersonID {get; set;}
    public decimal PAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal SAmount { get; set; }  
}
```

To hold the result of 4 kinds of queries:

1. `Person`s with a `PrivateAccount` and no `SharedAccount`.
2. `Person`s with no `PrivateAccount` and with a `SharedAccount`.
3. `Person`s with both `PrivateAccount` and a `SharedAccount`.
4. `Person`s with no `PrivateAccount` and no `SharedAccount`.

Here are the queries:

```
var PAccount = (from person in PersonList
                    where person.PrivateAccount != null
                    join account in accountList on person.PrivateAccount.AccountId equals account.AccountId
                    select new PersonWithAmounts { PersonID = person.ID, PAmount = account.Amount })
                    .ToList();

var SAccount = (from person in PersonList
                     where person.SharedAccount != null
                     join account in accountList on person.SharedAccount.AccountId equals account.AccountId
                     select new PersonWithAmounts {PersonID = person.ID, SAmount = account.Amount })
                    .ToList();

var noAccount = (from person in PersonList
                 where person.PrivateAccount == null && person.SharedAccount == null
                 select new PersonWithAmounts { PersonID = person.ID })
                 .ToList();
```

I have a feeling that what I did to merge them into a single list is complicated for no need, and would like to know how to make it more readable (and maybe more efficient):

```
var resultGroup = PAccount
                  .Concat(SAccount)
                  .Concat(noAccount)
                  .GroupBy(p => p.PersonID)
                  .Select(p => new PersonWithAmounts
                   {
                       PersonID = p.Key,
                       PAmount = p.Select(a => a.PAmount).ElementAt(0),
                       SAmount = p.Select(a => a.SAmount).Count() > 1 ? 
                                 p.Select(a => a.SAmount).ElementAt(1) : 
                                 p.Select(a => a.SAmount).ElementAt(0)
                   })
                  .ToList();
```

[Example program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JKDcST)

**NOTE**: The 3 lists are given and I have to work with them (For anyone who'd like to know why, I'm using Dynamics CRM and its LINQ provider can't be used as the regular one, So I need to stick to quite-simple queries).

**Clarifications**

1. As mentioned, `PersonWithAmounts` is a class created by me, so it's not mandatory.
2. I said I'm doing "4 queries", but actually meant that I need to end up with 4 different types of `Person`s. The final query (`resultGroup`) achieve it, but as commented, I make a problematic assumption regarding the order of the result of `GroupBy`.
3. The result of `resultGroup` shall include all records of `PersonList` (The aforementioned 4 types). I think the linked example demonstrates it.
4. Please run the following - It's a representation of my input & desired output (taken from LinqPad):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML []>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="Generator" content="LINQ to XML, baby!" />
    <style type="text/css">
body {
 margin: 0.3em 0.3em 0.4em 0.4em;
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-size: 80%;
 background: white
}

p, pre {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 font-family: Verdana;
}

table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: 2px solid #17b;
 margin: 0.3em 0.2em;
}

table.limit {
 border-bottom-color: #c31;
}

table.expandable {
 border-bottom-style: dashed;
}

table.error {
 border-bottom-width: 4px;
}

td, th {
 vertical-align: top;
 border: 1px solid #aaa;
 padding: 0.1em 0.2em;
 margin: 0;
}

th {
 text-align: left;
 background-color: #ddd;
 border: 1px solid #777;
 font-family: tahoma;
 font-size:90%;
 font-weight: bold;
}

th.member {
 padding: 0.1em 0.2em 0.1em 0.2em;
}

td.typeheader {
 font-family: tahoma;
 font-size: 100%;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: #17b;
 color: white;
 padding: 0 0.2em 0.15em 0.1em;
}

td.n { text-align: right }

a:link.typeheader, a:visited.typeheader, a:link.extenser, a:visited.extenser, a:link.fixedextenser, a:visited.fixedextenser {
 font-family: tahoma;
 font-size: 90%;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #17b;
 color: white;
 float:left;
}

a:link.extenser, a:visited.extenser, a:link.fixedextenser, a:visited.fixedextenser {
 float:right; 
 padding-left:2pt;
 margin-left:4pt
}

span.typeglyph, span.typeglyphx {
 padding: 0 0.2em 0 0;
 margin: 0;
}

span.extenser, span.extenserx, span.fixedextenser { 
 margin-top:1.2pt;
}

span.typeglyph, span.extenser, span.fixedextenser {
 font-family: webdings;
}

span.fixedextenser {
 display:none;
 position:fixed;
 right:6px;
}

td.typeheader:hover .fixedextenser {
 display:block
}

span.typeglyphx, span.extenserx {
 font-family: arial;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 2px;
}

table.group {
 border: none;
 margin: 0;
}

td.group {
 border: none;
 padding: 0 0.1em;
}

div.spacer { margin: 0.6em 0; }

table.headingpresenter {
 border: none;
 border-left: 3px dotted #1a5;
 margin: 1em 0em 1.2em 0.15em;
}

th.headingpresenter {
 font-family: Arial;
 border: none;
 padding: 0 0 0.2em 0.5em;
 background-color: white;
 color: green;
 font-size: 110%;        
}

td.headingpresenter {
 border: none;
 padding: 0 0 0 0.6em;
}

td.summary { 
 background-color: #def;
 color: #024;
 font-family: Tahoma;
 padding: 0 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em;
}

td.columntotal {
 font-family: Tahoma;
 background-color: #eee;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #17b;
 font-size:90%;
 text-align:right;
}

span.graphbar {
 background: #17b;
 color: #17b;
 margin-left: -2px;
 margin-right: -2px;
}

a:link.graphcolumn, a:visited.graphcolumn {
 color: #17b;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 110%;
 letter-spacing: -0.2em; 
 margin-left: 0.3em;
 margin-right: 0.1em;
}

a:link.collection, a:visited.collection { color:green }

a:link.reference, a:visited.reference { color:blue }

i { color: green }

em { color:red; }

span.highlight { background: #ff8 }

code { font-family: Consolas }

code.xml b { color:blue; font-weight:normal }
code.xml i { color:maroon; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal }
code.xml em { color:red; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal }
    </style>

    
  </head>
<body><div class="spacer"><table id="t1"><tr><td class="typeheader" colspan="3">List&lt;Person&gt; (4 items)<span class="fixedextenser">4</span></td></tr><tr><th title="System.Guid">ID</th><th title="UserQuery+Account">PrivateAccount</th><th title="UserQuery+Account">SharedAccount</th></tr><tr><td>ab65bd04-1789-462d-88b5-6a99ab3ded35</td><td><table id="t2"><tr><td class="typeheader" colspan="2">Account<span class="fixedextenser">4</span></td></tr><tr id="sum3"><td colspan="2" class="summary">UserQuery+Account</td></tr><tr><th class="member" title="System.Guid">AccountId</th><td>aaaaaaaa-4525-4bfe-9e2c-a7afff0dda1f</td></tr><tr><th class="member" title="System.Decimal">Amount</th><td>100</td></tr></table></td><td><i>null</i></td></tr><tr><td>594e4a34-be98-479f-b5b5-91bb29aff98e</td><td><i>null</i></td><td><table id="t4"><tr><td class="typeheader" colspan="2">Account<span class="fixedextenser">4</span></td></tr><tr id="sum5"><td colspan="2" class="summary">UserQuery+Account</td></tr><tr><th class="member" title="System.Guid">AccountId</th><td>eeeeeeee-4525-4bfe-9e2c-a7afff0dda1f</td></tr><tr><th class="member" title="System.Decimal">Amount</th><td>2000</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>d6735efe-2c4b-4e87-a0cb-7aaf9539994f</td><td><table id="t6"><tr><td class="typeheader" colspan="2">Account<span class="fixedextenser">4</span></td></tr><tr id="sum7"><td colspan="2" class="summary">UserQuery+Account</td></tr><tr><th class="member" title="System.Guid">AccountId</th><td>cccccccc-4525-4bfe-9e2c-a7afff0dda1f</td></tr><tr><th class="member" title="System.Decimal">Amount</th><td>300</td></tr></table></td><td><table id="t8"><tr><td class="typeheader" colspan="2">Account<span class="fixedextenser">4</span></td></tr><tr id="sum9"><td colspan="2" class="summary">UserQuery+Account</td></tr><tr><th class="member" title="System.Guid">AccountId</th><td>ffffffff-4525-4bfe-9e2c-a7afff0dda1f</td></tr><tr><th class="member" title="System.Decimal">Amount</th><td>3000</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>dad6db35-ed55-49b1-a9ff-4ddb1a3a2989</td><td><i>null</i></td><td><i>null</i></td></tr></table></div><div class="spacer"><table id="t10"><tr><td class="typeheader" colspan="3">List&lt;PersonWithAmounts&gt; (4 items)<span class="fixedextenser">4</span></td></tr><tr><th title="System.Guid">PersonID</th><th title="System.Decimal">PAmount</th><th title="System.Decimal">SAmount</th></tr><tr><td>ab65bd04-1789-462d-88b5-6a99ab3ded35</td><td class="n">100</td><td class="n">0</td></tr><tr><td>d6735efe-2c4b-4e87-a0cb-7aaf9539994f</td><td class="n">300</td><td class="n">3000</td></tr><tr><td>594e4a34-be98-479f-b5b5-91bb29aff98e</td><td class="n">0</td><td class="n">2000</td></tr><tr><td>dad6db35-ed55-49b1-a9ff-4ddb1a3a2989</td><td class="n">0</td><td class="n">0</td></tr><tr><td title="Totals" class="columntotal"></td><td title="Total=400&#xD;&#xA;Average=100" class="columntotal">400</td><td title="Total=5000&#xD;&#xA;Average=1250" class="columntotal">5000</td></tr></table></div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: 2 clarifications: 1. Is your desired output is a single `List<PersonWithAmounts>` populated from the 4 queries? 2. Are there any records in your data store that **would not be returned** by one of the 4 queries?

Comment: You can't assume the `GroupBy` will leave your `PersonWithAmounts` from the sub-queries in the right order, and since there is no way to tell a `PersonWithAmounts` with no accounts from a `PersonWithAmounts` with both Private and Shared accounts with 0 balances, your combination really isn't right.

Comment: I changed your names but I think the use of Only is misleading and incorrect - it isn't Person with Private Account Only, it is Person with Private Account. A person could end up in both PAccountOnly and SAccountOnly, I'll try to edit again. Also, why do the queries pull from different PersonLists?

Comment: I don't see any way to answer since your four query description doesn't match up to the three queries at all. If your three queries are really 1, 2 and 4, you can't compute 3 from that.

Comment: @ShaiCohen and NetMage, please see edits

Comment: Your question still seems (very) unclear. You say you create PersonWithAmounts,  you talk about 4 queries, you show 3 queries, then you say you can't change the 3 lists, then you provide an example with one list and one output. 1. What are the 3 lists provided and what do they look like? 2. What are the 3 queries shown? 3. Why don't the 3 queries reference 3 lists? 3. If your desired result is 4 types of queries, why do you show an example of one combined query?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 3 queries are meant to represent the 3 lists provided that can't be changed, I would suggest the simplest solution is to extract the pieces needed to put together the combined answer:

```
var PAccountOnly = from p in PAccount where p.SharedAccount == null select p;
var SAccountOnly = from s in SAccount where s.PrivateAccount == null select s;
var PandSAccounts = from p in PAccount
                   join s in SAccount on p.PersonID equals s.PersonID
                   select new PersonWithAmounts { PersonID = p.PersonID, PAmount = p.PAmount, SAmount = s.SAmount };
var allAccounts = PAccountOnly.Concat(SAccountOnly).Concat(PandSAccounts).Concat(noAccount).ToList();
```